# Conditional transform for XDF file

Tags: r, microsoft-r

I have an XDF file in Microsoft R. This is a somewhat simplified version of my problem. It has 2 columns in it, one column is categorical, and contains indices, like "1", "2", "3", etc... all the way to "10". The second column is numerical. What I would like to do is create a 3 column, that is a transform of the 2nd column, but conditioned on the first column. I.e., something like

```
if col1 == '1' then col3 = col2*0.50 else if col2 == '2' then col3 = col2*0.80
```

and so on.

I know you can make transforms directly in R, but I don't know how to accomplish something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
MyDataset <- RxXdfData("./path/dataset.xdf") #the dataset you are using

# replace transFormedCol with the name of the col you want to use 
rxDataStep(inData = MyDataset,
           outFile = MyDataset,
           transforms = list(
             transFormedCol = ifelse(col1 == '1',col2*0.5,
                                     ifelse(col2 == '2', col2*0.8))), #etc...
           overwrite = TRUE
           )
```